# Ruby + ActiveRecord: Reading from the Database

Tags: html, ruby, activerecord

I've written a Ruby script that parses a tab-delimited text file and writes the output to a sqlite3 database with ActiveRecord. Next, I need to write another Ruby script to display the database's contents as static HTML.

The text file that I'm working with is a list of parts that my company has for sale. My database has one table; each row in the database is a different part, and each column is a different attribute of that part (i.e., size, weight, list price, and so on and so forth). I need to be able to sort the table by the "short description" column in alphabetical order, then output each row as a series of HTML tables.

I've got no idea what to do next. I've been working with Ruby for about two weeks, and I've been using ActiveRecord for about four days, so I'm a little lost. I've been Googling for an answer all morning, but I've not found anything like what I'm wanting to do.

Here's a copy of the sqlite3 table declaration, if it's any help:

```
CREATE TABLE parts_info(item_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, location TEXT, 
quantity INTEGER, make TEXT, year INTEGER, model TEXT, serial TEXT, volt INTEGER, 
phase INTEGER, weight INTEGER, list_price REAL, sold INTEGER, 
image_path TEXT, short_desc TEXT, long_desc TEXT, junk TEXT);
```

It very well may be that I'm approaching this from the wrong angle, and if that's the case, I am open to any suggestions as to how to do this better.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with activerecord is that you have a model that represents a row in your table, and activerecord automatically maps data from the database into instances of your object, and vice versa.

So, to create an HTML table, you want to retrieve a list of PartsInfo objects, and convert them to HTML.  There are a number of options to do that: You may want to use an [ERB](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/) template file to turn your object into the desired HTML.  You might want to look at the [Builder](http://ruby.about.com/od/gems/a/builder.htm) gem.

Edited to add: To get a list of the objects, you use the [ActiveRecord query methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).  E.g. `PartsInfo.all`.

Comment: Builder is incredible - I had no idea that anything like that existed.

I'm just wondering how I would go about retrieving the list of PartsInfo objects... that's what's got me stumped.

Comment: Edited to add a link to the query guide.  The one in my post is the one for Rails 3 (it sounds like you're using ActiveRecord outside of Rails, which implies Rails 3; if not, here's the link for Rails 2:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Yeah, I am using Ruby outside of Rails.

Model.Find has brought to light some new issues. I launched IRB and connected to the database with ActiveRecord to test some things.

`part = Part.first` displays the row and column data for the entry, but it seems as if the item_number that I passed to the database has been overwritten with an auto-incrementing value. part = `Part.find(0)`, however, gives me a huge error message that starts `NoMethodError: undefined method eq for nil:NilClass` - same for any other id. What gives?

Comment: ActiveRecord will indeed use an autoincremented value as the id (primary key) unless you tell it otherwise.  You can use `set_primary_key` to alter the primary key, and put `:id=>false` in your migration to tell it not to add an autoincrementing id column.

Comment: Do I even have to have a primary key at all? Given that I can sort the database by any column, I don't see any benefits outside of having it auto-increment, which I don't need.

Comment: No, you don't need a primary key.  The `find` method won't work without it, but there are plenty of other query approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an ActiveRecord model, you can return the entire contents of the model's table with `ModelName.all`. Another option for iterating over all records in a table is the `ModelName.find_each` method. This lets you effeciently do something like the following.

```
ModelName.find_each do |model_var|
  <tr>
    <td>model_var.attribute_1</td>
    <td>model_var.attribute_2</td>
    # and so on...
  </tr>
end
```

Obviously this is very simple, perhaps even primitive, but if all you need is dump text to a file, this will work. If you need to construct this html on the fly, then you should look into an MVC framework like Rails or Sinatra.

Comment: I'm guessing that ModelName and model_var are just placeholders for my code?

Comment: `ModelName` is a placeholder for the name of your model.  `model_var` can be anything you want -- it's a local variable that gets populated with each instance of your model (one by one).

Comment: @Jean good deal, that was throwing me off a little. Thanks to you too, @yock.